# Pointer to **column_array of 2d dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, reference

I have been working on a matrix library project similar to the vector library and am currently stuck at iterators. I have been trying to implement a column iterator for quite some time without the use of other libraries (besides iostream and fstream) and my workaround was to have a **columnVector that contains the references of a specified column when colBegin(i) or colEnd(i) is called. The implementation works but I can't manage to make it work aesthetically without going in myMatrix.columnVector as I want it to be encapsulated, rather I want to call matrix::iterator it = myMatrix.colBegin(i) and to iterate with addition and subtraction but my iterator subclass has only a 1d pointer (for the row iterator, hope I can use it for the column iterator as well).
*Do you have an idea how to make a column iterator for a dynamically allocated 2d array?*

#### Example of code (trying to keep it as short as possible):

```
using ll = unsigned long long;

template <typename Type> class matrix
{
// Iterator
public:
    class iterator
    {
    protected:
        Type* pointer;

    public:
        iterator() : pointer(nullptr) {}
        iterator(Type* ptr);

        Type& operator * ();
        ...
    };

private:
    ll numberOfColumns, numberOfRows;
    Type** data;

public:    // temporary, wish for it to be private
    Type** columnVector;

public:
    matrix() :  numberOfColumns(NULL), numberOfRows(NULL), data(nullptr), columnVector(nullptr) {}
    matrix(const ll, const ll);
    ~matrix();

    Type*& operator [] (const ll value);

    Type** colBegin(const ll index);
    Type** colEnd(const ll index);
    ...
};

// Thought the constructor might be important since it allocates memory for columnVector as well
template <typename Type> matrix<Type> ::matrix(const ll _numberOfColumns, const ll _numberOfRows)
{
    // Copy _numberOfColumns and _numberOfRows into this
    numberOfColumns = _numberOfColumns;
    numberOfRows = _numberOfRows;
    
    // Allocates memory for data matrix
    other.data = (Type**) new Type * [numberOfColumns];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        other.data[i] = (Type*) new Type[numberOfRows];
    
    // Fills data matrix with 0
    for (size_t i = 0; i < other.numberOfColumns; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < other.numberOfRows; j++)
            other.data[i][j] = 0;

    // Allocation of space for columnVector
    columnVector = new Type * [numberOfRows];
}

template <typename Type> Type** matrix<Type> ::colBegin(const ll index)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        columnVector[i] = &data[i][index];
    return columnVector;
}

template <typename Type> Type** matrix<Type> ::colEnd(const ll index)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        columnVector[i] = &data[i][index];
    return (columnVector + numberOfRows);
}
```

Comment: What do you think your column iterator should return as the value?

Comment: I want it to return a pointer to the double pointer array (I know I wrote the function as return type ** but I am still experimenting with it) but I can't quite wrap my head around it nor can I think of a way for it to be feasible.

Comment: Also forgot to answer your question, if I do something like matrix<type> iterator it = colBegin(col_number) and my it works as a 1d pointer and colBegin returns a 2d pointer it dereferences what's returned. If I want to get the stored value I have to double dereference name.columnVector + i, 0 <= i <= colSize - 1 and if I try to work with an iterator it it does something like *( *name.columnVector + i). That's what I think it does @Dmitry Kuzminov

Comment: What do you plan to do with this `T**`? What element shoul it point to? What should happen if you increment this iterator?

Comment: I want columnVector** to store the respective column's addresses when calling colBegin(i) or colEnd(i) and want a way to parse columnVector, ideally with an iterator T*. I want it easy to use, for example
`matrix<T>::iterator it; // for filling colVector with addresses to first col`
`for(it = colBegin(0); it != colEnd(0); it++) std::cout << *it;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need an iterator. Each column is represented with an array. To iterate this array you need to know its beginning and the address of the element after the last one. So the `Type*` can represent you the iterator:

```cpp
template <typename Type> class matrix
{
public:
    using column_iterator = Type*;
};
```

So the `colBegin`/`colEnd` methods should look like that:

```cpp
template<typename Type>
matrix<Type>::column_iterator matrix<Type>::colBegin(const ll index) {
    return data[index];
}

template<typename Type>
matrix<Type>::column_iterator matrix<Type>::colEnd(const ll index) {
    return data[index] + numberOfRows;
}
```

If you find that the code above iterates throught the row (which is not the case, as your contructor clearly describes `data[i]` as a column), you may define a class that represents an iterator:

```cpp
class row_iterator {
public:
    row_iterator(Type** data,
                 size_t rowIndex,
                 size_t columnIndex)
      : m_data(data), m_rowIndex(rowIndex), m_columnIndex(columnIndex) {
    }
    bool operator == (const row_iterator &other) const {
        return other.data == m_data &&
               other.m_rowIndex == m_rowIndex &&
               other.m_columnIndex == m_columnIndex;
    }
    row_iterator& operator ++() {
        ++m_columnIndex;
        return *this;
    }
    row_iterator& operator ++(int) {
        row_iterator temp = *this;
        ++*this;
        return temp;
    }
    Type& operator *() const {
        return m_data[m_columnIndex][m_rowIndex];
    }
    // other operators
private:
    Type** m_data;
    size_t m_rowIndex;
    size_t m_columnIndex;
};
```

To use this iterator with the container you need to define:

```cpp
    row_iterator rowBegin(size_t rowIndex) {
        return row_iterator(data, rowIndex, 0);
    }
    row_iterator rowEnd(size_t rowIndex) {
        return row_iterator(rowIndex, rowIndex, numberOfColumns);
    }
```

Comment: That iterates throught the *row*, not column.

Comment: See the updates.